# how to tune mapred.reduce.parallel.copies?

Tags: hadoop

Following reading http://gbif.blogspot.com/2011/01/setting-up-hadoop-cluster-part-1-manual.html we want to experiment with mapred.reduce.parallel.copies.

The blog mentions "looking very carefully at the logs". How would we know we've reached the sweet spot? what should we look for? how can we detect that we're over-parallelizing?

Answer (score 7):

In order to do that you should basically look for 4 things : CPU, RAM, Disk and Network. If your setup is crossing the threshold of these metrics you can deduce that you are pushing the limits. For example, if you have set the value of "mapred.reduce.parallel.copies" to a value much higher than the number of cores available, you'll end up with too many threads in waiting state, as based on this property Threads will be created to fetch the Map output. In addition to that network might get overwhelmed. Or, if there is too much intermediate output to be shuffled , your job will become slow as you will need disk based shuffle in such a case, which will be slower than RAM based shuffle. Choose a wise value for "mapred.job.shuffle.input.buffer.percent" based on your RAM(defaults to 70% of Reducer heap, which is normally good). So, these are kinda things which will tell you whether you are over-parallelizing or not. There are a lot of other things as well which you should consider. I would recommend you to go through the Chapter 6 of "Hadoop Definitve Guide".

Some of the measures which you could take, in order to make your jobs efficient, are like using a combiner to limit the data transfer, enable intermediate compression etc.

HTH

P.S : The answer is not very specific to just "mapred.reduce.parallel.copies". It tells you about tuning your job in general. Actually speaking setting only this property is not gonna help you much. You should consider other important properties as well.

Answer (score 1):

Reaching the "sweet spot" is really just finding the parameters that give you the best result for whichever metric you consider the most important, usually overall job time. To figure out what parameters are working I would suggest using the following profiling tools that Hadoop comes with, MrBench, TestDFSIO, and NNBench. These are found in the hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-*.jar.

By running this command you will see a long list of benchmark programs that you can use besides the ones I mentioned above.

> hadoop ./share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-*.jar

I would suggest running with the default parameters, run tests to give baseline benchmarks, then changing one parameter and rerunning. A bit time consuming but worth it, especially if you use a script to change parameters and run the benchmarks.

Comment: Using this tool, is it possible to benchmark hadoop streaming jobs as well ?

Comment: Not directly no. Each of those is a full map/reduce program and Hadoop Streaming wants specified mappers and reducers. That being said, one of these programs could still be used if you looked at the code and directly specified the mapper and reducer class from their jars. I would hope that the result of this would be nearly identical to just running the program directly, but you would have to try it to be sure.